# With gridview changes how to update back to the datasource?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, .net-4.5

With the new frameworks coming up in .NET(4.5, 4.0, 3.5 etc) and with many more features....
Is there a simple/straight forward with less optimize code to track the changes of Gridview data and updating the same back to DataSource(SQL Server DB) in much efficient way towards High performance?

As i came across different ways to update the changes back to Datasource.
But i need very optimize using new framework concepts or features.

if there is no better way please help me out how to update the changes of Gridview to DataSource  in a Bi-directional data binding concept towards high performance.

A sample DataTable:

```
Skill_Name  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
dotnet      40  20  30  60
java        10  20  60  70
Testing     50  30  55  35
SAP         70  45  25  90
Databases   100 200 300 400
```

**Grid Output**:
[image]

If the user done some changes in the Grid and click the Button `Save To DB` then How the changes to be tracked and gets updated to DB in an optimized way towards HIGH performance.

Currently i'm doing updating each row-by-row into DB. This leads to me the site very slow.

Please help me in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored proc with table value parameters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

and do MERGE

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: First How to track the changes of the gridview into a datatable or any collection object and to update the same back to DB?

Comment: I would just pass post the whole view model to the controller action (I assume that you're using proper View Models) and than pass it down to the service layer (I assume you have service layer) after mapping models to dtos using AutoMapper. I don't know how your architecture looks like so it's hard to tell.